# import from parent directory python

Tags: pytest

I am trying to run a pytest test for filea.py using the following directory structure

test_filea.py

```py
from filea import *

def test_one_p_one():
    r = one_p_one()
    assert r == 2
```

filea.py

```py
def one_p_one():
    return 1 + 1
```

When i have to following directory structure every thing works fine.

```
├── filea.py
├── test_filea.py
```

but when i move my tests into a sub directory like this

```
├── filea.py
└── tests
    └── test_filea.py
```

i get the error:

```
test_filea.py:1: in <module>
    from filea import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filea'
```

My editor seems to indicate the import in the file in the sub directory is ok.. (no read squiggly lines)

but when i run this using "pytest"

i get the error indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

As per pytest documentation about [test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery), try like this:

- add an empty `__init__.py` file in `tests`directory;
- make sure that, when you run `pytest .`, the parent directory of `filea.py` and `tests` is the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you run the tests from, and how you invoke pytest.  Calling `pytest tests` is different than calling `python -m pytest tests`, the later adds the current working directory into the sys.path, which makes `filea` module importable.